# How to define array of fixed size from other preinitialized array

Tags: arrays, c

Get the size of an array depending on a size of another array whose size is determined automatically by the compiler and create a type out of that.

How to get the size of an array beforehand to define another array of same size?

I like to have the "notWorking" array to have the same number of elements like the test[] array. Any ideas? (The definition of test[] should stay where it is within the main.c, after the #include.)

Is there any possibility to define content which stays in the header file to be then responsible for getting the same array element number definition for both arrays (the preinitialized one and the other one, which only exist as a type)?

### main.c

```
#include "main.h"

const MyStruct_t test[] = {
    { 42u },
    { 23u },
};

uint32_t working[ ALEN( test ) ];

int
main()
{
    printf( "myStruct[]=%d\n", sizeof( test ) / sizeof( test[ 0 ] ) );
    printf( "working[]=%d\n", sizeof( working ) / sizeof( working[ 0 ] ) );
#if 0
    printf( "notWorking[]=%d\n", sizeof( notWorking ) / sizeof( notWorking[ 0 ] ) );
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

### main.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define ALEN( A ) ( sizeof( A ) / sizeof( ( A )[ 0 ] ) )
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t x;
} MyStruct_t;
#if 0
// not working; "test" not yet seen by the compiler
typedef uint32_t notWorking[ ALEN( test ) ];
#endif
```

Comment: I see that the question title may not well reflect the actual question you mean to ask, but to that alternative question: there is no way to compute any properties of an object that has no in-scope declaration.

Comment: Sorry, but the TL;DR is that (as you surmised), the `notWorking` version can't be done because `test` _must_ be seen/defined _before_ doing `ALEN(test)`. There are alternate ways to get the same effect. (e.g.) `#define MAXCOUNT 2` in `main.h` and `uint32_t notWorking[MAXCOUNT];` However, in `main.h` you can just do: `uint32_t notWorking[];` This is okay, since, in `main.c` you _can_ do (e.g.): `for (int i = 0; i < ALEN(test); ++i) notWorking[i] = i;` In either case, the compiler won't enforce a range check.

Comment: fully understood, but explicitly setting the size (e.g with the #define) was not the intention. I wanted to derive sizes of arrays from the compiler calculation and not only the one which is initialized, but others as well.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to place th initialize into some #define ? so that the init is done automatically and the array sizes are given as well ... ?

Comment: Is there any reason why `working` shouldn't be collated with `test`?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the size of an array beforehand to define another array of same size?

It is impossible to get the size of an array before defining that array.

> How to define array of fixed size from other preinitialized array

You can:

- just add the definition of `test` to `main.h` and use the `ALEN` macro,
- or use an external program to get the size of the array after compiling `main.c` and from it generate `main.h` file or generate a preprocessor macro for compilation of any other files dependent on `main.h`,
- or hardcode the value of the array size in `main.h` and write a `static_assert` into `main.c`,
- or get the pointer to the array and the size of the array with runtime functions defined in `main.c` like `uint32_t *getNotWorkingArray(size_t *size);`.

Comment: These are insprations. The intention was to get compile-time results without linker tricks or inline problematic. Just something that always works/is always correct "in a simple way" ...